# marble mouse middle click fail in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xorg, gnome, mouse

On recently upgrading to 12.04, I find that the middle click with my logictec marble mouse doesn't work any more (formally achieved by clicking both buttons). Anoying since I can't do a middle-click paste.

Can anyone think of an easy solution? Or should I file a bug?

(theres's already a [launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+question/190515) on this, and here's the oldish [ubuntu page for configuring a marble mouse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/874237/comments/13) and [here](http://who-t.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/gnome-30-middle-mouse-button-emulation.html). You need to run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse middle-button-enabled true
```

You only need to do this once - Gnome remebers the setting for your next logon - though you need to do it for each user. If someone knows a way around this, feel free to edit this answer (:

It seems Gnome sets this to 'false' by default, and does so **after** xorg does it's settings (so it overrides xorg settings in `xorg.conf` or `...-evdev.conf` etc..)

The setting can also be changed with the `dconf-editor` in the `dconf-tools` package ([thanks Walt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/874237/comments/19)). Go to org::gnome::settings-daemon::peripherals::mouse and tick 'middle-button-enabled'.

Comment: No such schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse'.

Comment: @DaveJarvis can you provide more info? The above commands all still work for me..

Comment: I found a work-around: http://askubuntu.com/a/272009/64957 ... Don't know why `gsettings` couldn't find the schema.

Comment: @Dave I think I see the difference now: It seems Xubuntu 12.04 LTS running Xfce does not override those X settings, so changing the xorg files works. Looks like the mouse settings have been removed from Xfce/Xubuntu (hence the 'No such schema' error).

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME 3. I tried `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse middle-button-enabled true` but it says `No such key 'middle-button-enabled'`.  Any thoughts to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem after updating from 10.04. I have applied the settings to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf as suggested in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Marble_Mouse and this gives the required scrolling using the trackball, but the two-large-button middle-click merely gives a right-click effect.

I have appended the following settings ing 10-evdev.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "Marble Mouse"
        MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 2"
        Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
        Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"
        Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
        Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
        Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
EndSection
```

This maps the middle button click to either of the small buttons (8 & 9) and allows the holding down of button 8 (small left button) for the track-ball scrolling. While not ideal (I also prefer the two-large-button==middle-click) this might be a good enough compromise (I think it will be for me at least).

I would also suggest that the loss of Emulate3Buttons is a bug and should be reported. This setting worked fine with this mouse on 10.04.

Comment: Thanks theabro. Doesn't actually answer the question, but its good to have this info here (:

Comment: That's great drevicko - that now gives the middle-click working on my system. The line 

     Option "Emulate3Buttons" "false"

will need to be changed to 

     Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"

for this as well I think.

Comment: yep, it will (: I'll change it in the question now..