# How do I set up custom options for mouse middleclick?

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I have a mouse that I suppose nowadays is quite uncommon, Logitech Usb Marble mouse. There was a [question about this specific mouse](https://askubuntu.com/q/133648/114660), however it was too localized as it dealt with Ubuntu 12.04 and older versions and the solution no longer applies. In the question, there was a link to an [Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB) specifically designed for my model mouse, however it hasn't been updated in years and the solutions are no longer compatible with 12.10 and up.

Creating a 50-marblemouse.conf file as directed for earlier versions of Ubuntu causes the system to break. I have to usb boot and delete the offending file before I can run my distribution again.

So the question is, how do I customize my mouse button functions (i.e. pressing the two smaller mouse buttons to simulate a middle mouse button click) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Marble_Mouse#Configuration_file

To cut a long story short, making the required edits in `10-evdev.conf` and not in `50-marblemouse.conf` did the job for me.

Comment: Please add the relevant steps from the link into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04:

1. edit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf, e.g. `sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`
2. add the below block to the end of `10-evdev.conf`
3. log out and back in

Copied from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Marble_Mouse#Configuration_file :

```
#       - - - Logitech Marble Mouse Settings - - -
#
#       The Logitech Marble Mouse buttons are mapped [A-D] from left to right: 
#       A (large); B (small) |  C (small); D (large). 
#
#       Preferred options for right-handed usage:
#       A = normal click [1]  
#       B = middle-click [2] 
#       C = middle-click [2] 
#       D = right-click [3]
#       Hold button B while rolling trackball to emulate wheel-scrolling. 
#
#       Preferred options for left-handed usage:
#       A = right-click [3]  
#       B = middle-click [2] 
#       C = middle-click [2]
#       D = normal click [1]
#       Hold button C while rolling trackball to emulate wheel-scrolling.
#       Pressing both large buttons simultaneously (b) produces a "back" action.

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "Marble Mouse"
        MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"

#       Physical button #s:     A b D - - - - B C    
#       Option "ButtonMapping" "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 2"   right-hand placement
#       Option "ButtonMapping" "3 8 1 4 5 6 7 2 2"   left-hand placement
#       b = A & D 
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 2 2"

#       EmulateWheel: Use Marble Mouse trackball as mouse wheel 
#       Factory Default: 8; Use 9 for right side small button
        Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
        Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"

#       EmulateWheelInertia: How far (in pixels) the pointer must move to
#       generate button press/release events in wheel emulation mode.
#       Factory Default: 50
        Option "EmulateWheelInertia" "10"

#       Axis Mapping: Enable vertical [ZAxis] and horizontal [XAxis] scrolling
        Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
#       Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"

#       Emulate3Buttons: Required to interpret simultaneous press of two large
#       buttons, A & D, as a seperate command, b.
#       Factory Default: true
        Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 17 and in XFCE the middle mouse button copy paste did not work at all.

SOLUTION:

To enable the middle mouse button paste do edit the xinput.

a) Query your device: 
xinput list

Identify your mouse. With me it was device number 10.

b) xinput list-props 10

Gives me the settings for the mouse.

c) I need to change the value for "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (294):" and I need to do it as root:

sudo xinput set-prop 10 "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled" 1

d) Check if the value changed to 1:

xinput list-props 10

Yes, it works: "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (294):    1"

What is behind it:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input

I strongly disagree that Ubuntu and Gnome decided to disable the standard Unix Middle Mouse paste. Even in XFCE Ubuntu 17 it is devastated.

Many, many thanks to Gilles (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) who found the solution!!!